# Error while clicking on element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to click on the 'Make a payment' icon but I'm not able to click on it using XPath.

I used:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='a11y appmagic-button-busy']//button[@class='appmagic-button-container no-focus-outline' and @title='Click here to make a payment']").click()
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the XPath you are using is that it's looking for a BUTTON that's a *descendant* of a DIV but that DIV is actually a sibling of the desired BUTTON.

Given the HTML you posted, if you just remove the DIV portion of the XPath, the rest should work.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='appmagic-button-container no-focus-outline' and @title='Click here to make a payment']").click()
```

Having said that, there's an issue with XPaths like this. Your @class has to be an exact string match so if a different class gets added to that element or the order of the classes is changed, the XPath will no longer find the element. You'd be better off in this case using a CSS selector like

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.appmagic-button-container.no-focus-outline[title='Click here to make a payment']").click()
```

or you can likely simplify it even more to

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Click here to make a payment']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the [Make a payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juzI7.png) element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.appmagic-button-container.no-focus-outline[title='Click here to make a payment']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='appmagic-button-container no-focus-outline' and @title='Click here to make a payment']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```